# How to create a Python list from a JSON object?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm writing a script in Python, using the flickr.photos.search API to retrieve a JSON object containing ids and infos of photos with a specific tag.

```
response = flickr.photos.search(api_key = api_key, tags='painting')
```

This is what "response" looks like:

```
{'photos': {'page': 1, 'pages': 7112, 'perpage': 100, 'total': '711114', 'photo': [

{'id': '33675403798', 'owner': '93779577@N00', 'secret': 'cb33cbcde6', 'server': '7914', 'farm': 8, 'title': ' Door 5302AA', 'ispublic': 1, 'isfriend': 0, 'isfamily': 0}, 

{'id': '40586047293', 'owner': '93779577@N00', 'secret': 'd4a0df639e', 'server': '7849', 'farm': 8, 'title': 'Elevator Door 5302', 'ispublic': 1, 'isfriend': 0, 'isfamily': 0}, 

{'id': '33675168088', 'owner': '164939965@N03', 'secret': '8d271064e7', 'server': '7857', 'farm': 8, 'title': 'A New Shade Of Blue', 'ispublic': 1, 'isfriend': 0, 'isfamily': 0}, 

{'id': '32582314737', 'owner': '81035653@N00', 'secret': 'e78b4f7235', 'server': '7821', 'farm': 8, 'title': 'Saint Michael', 'ispublic': 1, 'isfriend': 0, 'isfamily': 0}, 

]}, 

'stat': 'ok'}
```

From this I would like to create Python list that contains only the "id"s of the photos, something that would look like this:

```
['33675403798', '40586047293', '33675168088', '32582314737']
```

How can I extract only the ids and create a list?

**EDIT:**
Thank you to anyone who took the time to help me!
I managed to create the list using this code:

```
tag="painting"
response = flickr.photos.search(api_key = api_key, tags=tag)

photo_list=[]
for record in response['photos']['photo']:
    s=record["id"]
    photo_list.append(s)
```

I hope it can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `flickr.photos.search` already parses the JSON for you, you can access the `photo` list with `response["photos"]["photo"]`.

Then, you can create a list containing only the ids you need with a list comprehension (a more Pythonic equivalent to a for loop to create a list):

```py
photo_ids = [photo["id"] for photo in response["photos"]["photo"]]
```

The for loop equivalent for this code would be:

```py
photo_ids = []
for photo in response["photos"]["photo"]:
    photo_ids.append(photo["id"])
```

Answer (score 1):

The flickr.photos.search() function returns you a dictionary containing other dictionaries. You are intereseted in the id's which are part of a dictionary (key: photos) which contains a list (key:photo) of dictionaries that have these values (key: id). You can extract your desired output with a list comprehension like that:

```
[photodict['id'] for photodict in response['photos']['photo']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**Step - 1:**

Set the dictionary to a variable, say `df`

```
df = {'photos': {'page': 1, 'pages': 7112, 'perpage': 100, 'total': '711114', 'photo': [

{'id': '33675403798', 'owner': '93779577@N00', 'secret': 'cb33cbcde6', 'server': '7914', 'farm': 8, 'title': ' Door 5302AA', 'ispublic': 1, 'isfriend': 0, 'isfamily': 0}, 

{'id': '40586047293', 'owner': '93779577@N00', 'secret': 'd4a0df639e', 'server': '7849', 'farm': 8, 'title': 'Elevator Door 5302', 'ispublic': 1, 'isfriend': 0, 'isfamily': 0}, 

{'id': '33675168088', 'owner': '164939965@N03', 'secret': '8d271064e7', 'server': '7857', 'farm': 8, 'title': 'A New Shade Of Blue', 'ispublic': 1, 'isfriend': 0, 'isfamily': 0}, 

{'id': '32582314737', 'owner': '81035653@N00', 'secret': 'e78b4f7235', 'server': '7821', 'farm': 8, 'title': 'Saint Michael', 'ispublic': 1, 'isfriend': 0, 'isfamily': 0}, 

]}, 

'stat': 'ok'}
```

**Step-2:**

```
id_list = [df['photos']['photo'][i]['id'] for i in range(len(df['photos']['photo']))]
```

**Output:**
[image]