# How to create a json file from list in python?

Tags: python, json

I am tring to create a json file with my lists in my python code:

I have

```
arr_of_id_by_user = [1, 2, 3]
arr_of_wallet_amount = [100,3400,200]
```

I would like this to return in the json file like

```
jsonfile = [{
    "user" : 1,
    "wallet amount": 100
},
{
    "user" : 2,
    "wallet amount": 3400
},
{
    "user" : 3,
    "wallet amount": 200
}]
```

Is it possible to do that? I tried to do a `for` loop like this:

```
for elements in arr_of_id_by_user:
        return jsonify({
            "id": elements
        })
```

and `json.dumps()` but it don't work ...
maybe I have to do a tuple with `(user.value[0], wallet_amount.value[0])` ?

for peoples who try to do the reverse thing :
[How to create a Python list from a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554573/how-to-create-a-python-list-from-a-json-object)

I would like to thank all those who helped me and who participate in the learning of all.

Comment: What is `jsonfile` in your second snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the lists to list of dictionaries and dump this to the file

```
arr_of_id_by_user = [1, 2, 3]
arr_of_wallet_amount = [100, 3400, 200]
with open('file.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump([{'user': id, 'wallet amount': amount} for id, amount in zip(arr_of_id_by_user, arr_of_wallet_amount)], file)
```

`file.json`

```
[{"user": 1, "wallet amount": 100}, {"user": 2, "wallet amount": 3400}, {"user": 3, "wallet amount": 200}]
```

Comment: thakns ! it work ! I would really struggle, is it possible de do a rest api with this method ? i mean like : @app.route(/wallet, method: GET) => return a json file with this values ? thanks again for your help

Comment: @ax3lGarcia I think you are looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/return-json-response-from-flask-view

Comment: finaly i just do like that : resp = (open('file.json' , 'r') and return resp.read() and it work thanks because without you i was conviced that i was necessary to use jsonify

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution, using enumerate:

```
import json

arr_of_id_by_user = [1, 2, 3]
arr_of_wallet_amount = [100,3400,200]

jsonfile=[]

for index, value in enumerate(arr_of_id_by_user):
    jsonfile.append({
        "user": value,
        "waller_amount": arr_of_wallet_amount[index]
    }) 

print (json.dumps(jsonfile, indent=4))
```

Comment: `for user_id, amount in zip(arr_of_id_by_user, arr_of_wallet_amount)` is more "pythonic" way to iterate over multiple sequences.

Comment: I agree, I was just proposing an alternative solution, maybe less "pythonic" but perhaps more clear then using the zip function.

Answer (score 0):

Python List to JSON Array

```
list_example = ["Mango", 1, 3,6, "Oranges"];
print(json.dumps(list_example))
```